# Como juntar uma TabLayout na activity com um ViewPager dentro de um FrameLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, viewpager

Estou trabalhando num projeto onde preciso juntar um TabLayout que se encontra na activity com um ViewPager que está dentro de um fragment no FrameLayout da Activity.

Estou tentando de tudo, mas minha dúvida resumida é: Como eu consigo pegar esse ViewPager do fragment e uni-lo com o TabLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvido. Infelizmente estava tentando recuperar o código na activity, sendo que era muito mais fácil recuperá-lo dentro do fragment.

Simplesmente fiz o código abaixo:

! No Fragment !

```
mainTabs = activity.findViewById(R.id.main_tabs)
mainTabs.setupWithViewPager(mPager, false)
```

P.S: Kotlin.